# Older lenses on Nikon d3400

Tags: metering, dx, nikon-d3400

I’m new to photography, and I’m interested If I use older lenses like series E ,AF, AF-D or AF-G will I have problems with metering system or just have to use manual controls ?

Comment: Closely related: [Why will low-end Nikons not meter with old lenses?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/45467)

Comment: Possibly useful: [Can I control the aperture of a F-mount lens with aperture ring from the camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82109/can-i-control-the-aperture-of-a-f-mount-lens-with-aperture-ring-from-the-camera) and [Why is the aperture ring removed from new Nikon lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/why-is-the-aperture-ring-removed-from-new-nikon-lenses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you D3400 camera, meter will not operate with E lenses, and Autofocus only will work with AF-G lenses.

I always check [this page](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-slr-camera-and-lens-compatibility) for DSLR and lens compatibility when I am planning to buy an old lens.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you'll be fine. You will most likely not have auto focus but other than, I don't see any inherent issues with using older f mount lenses

Comment: If the camera is unable to control the aperture on the lens, stop-down metering will be required.

Comment: Well, it uses AF-P lenses without aperture ring, so i shouldn’t buy AF-D lenses? (I’m interested in 50mm 1.8D)

Comment: If you get a AF-D lens it will meter but not AF. Not important if you are okay with manually focusing the lens. And I'm think that this might only work in manual mode.